# android google maps on a webview

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps

I have a jqueryMobile app that uses google maps api and is working properly on iOS. However, I am not able to get it running on android. I set following permissions on my manifest file. File is loaded properly but I am not able to view the map! Assuming that jqmobile code is working because works on iOS, how to enable it or which steps are required? Thank you.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
```

my webview class looks like,

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        browse4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        browse4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browse4.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browse4.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        browse4.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        browse4.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        browse4.loadUrl("file:///data/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/files/" + "myMap.html");

    }
```

Comment: How are you getting your html file into your files dir? perhaps it is getting corrupted during that proccess? Try droping in a plain html page with just some text on it and see if the WebView shows your html that way.

Comment: html has no errors. Checked again. Also tested from remote server using android and iOS and for iOS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there any particular reason why you're not using the Google [MapView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)?

I understand it's using jQuery but this *might* be easier.

Comment: yes, for some reasons I need to use a webView. Should be an easy task... Truly it is on iOS but this issue is turning me crazy on android...

Comment: It's good that you have setJavaScriptEnabled(true) running first, but it may have something to do with jqmobile. If it's iOS specific, what is it? It could possibly be an error in the javascript, causing the rest of the page to not initialise correctly.

Comment: what was the solution to the problem? i need to port my mapView centric android app to use a webView with google maps loaded into it so that I can try to repackage my APK as a blackberry BAR.

Comment: @twig because we don't have to include the whole androidx library and the google maps library which are slow down the build and bloat the generated apk

Answer (score 0):

Might be a dumb answer but do you have this in your manifest?

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: It was worth a shot, I know I've made that mistake before

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this

Create a new project using Google API and try this.

```
package com.ab1209.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebMapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
{
    private static final String MAP_URL = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/simple-android-map.html";
    private WebView webView;

    Location mostRecentLocation;

    @Override
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getLocation();
        setupWebView();
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    private void getLocation()
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        // In order to make sure the device is getting the location, request
        // updates.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 0, this);
        mostRecentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /** Sets up the WebView object and loads the URL of the page **/
    private void setupWebView()
    {
        final String centerURL = "javascript:centerAt(" + mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mostRecentLocation.getLongitude() + ")";
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Wait for the page to load then send the location information
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(MAP_URL);
        /** Allows JavaScript calls to access application resources **/
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the interface for getting access to Latitude and Longitude data
     * from device
     **/
    private class JavaScriptInterface
    {
        public double getLatitude()
        {
            return mostRecentLocation.getLatitude();
        }

        public double getLongitude()
        {
            return mostRecentLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    }
}
```

Please also check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3).I had the same problem now it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the file like that.  You need to put it in your `assets` folder and then access it with `file:///android_asset/file_name.html`.  You can only access the `/data/data` folder directly if you have root access.